How can Ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10 be certified with Raspberry Pi5 and not work at all with RPi5 same time?
I've tried Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and 24.10 on Raspberry Pi5 8GB.
Cannonical says its "Ubuntu certified" hardware.
It is also a specific, definite hardware SOC - I mean there should be no "yes but your graphic card is different and has no good Ubuntu driver" like every previous time i tried Linux etc. It's closed + it's certified -> should be seamless right? Well - NO.
24.04 LTS for RPi5 taken straight from Pi Imager crashes at startup with blueish screen. Tried with 2x monitors 2x keyboards 2x mouses and 2x memories (32GB SD card that passed tests and 128 GB Samsung USB 3.1 dongle)
24.04 LTS for RPi5 taken from ubuntu site -> behaves differently which is already interesting - does not crash at startup bud does so when you start Snap app store, and if you start Firefox its windows is unreadable / not displayed properly.

disabling opengl helps Firefox to display window - but it becomes unusable - does not react.
disabling opengl for Snap store - changes nothing
switching to "Ubuntu on Xorg" changes colors of crashed windows

24.10 taken from Raspberry Imager does not crash at startup but has above problems with running both firefox and snap store.
And my Raspberry works just fine on Raspberry OS so I guess board itself is fine. It is also brand new bought from certified reseller.
How can it be? How do they do it in Cannonical? Literally don't bother to chceck if it works at all before badging "Ubuntu certified" or what?
How do you make it work?
Is there some magic trick to make it run, that everyone knows but I don't?
If so - why isn't it applied already - I mean it literally is Raspberry precompiled Ubuntu that does not work on Raspberry XD
